# fullscreen randomized grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would love to have a fullscreen filled grid, with only the number of divs that are currently available.

This is what I got so far: `check: http://jsfiddle.net/LqpTm/`

Screenshot fullscreen:
[image]
See for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749170/grid-with-fixed-width-and-height-fullscreen/21751479

Well, it is fullscreen right now, so far so good... But the problem is that it fills the gabs with duplications (clones), which is not good. The screen needs to be filled with ONLY the number of divs available, in a randomized grid. No divs more, no less.

Anyone knows a solution for how to get this done?

Comment: I could be wrong... but it might be a little much to ask people to sort through your whole script and fix it. You'd probably get better responses if you can ask a specific question about a specific section of your code. Hope it works out though, looks nice!

Comment: You're probably right :) I don't recieve that much responses right now XD Well... The problem is solved if I'd be able to merge the divs, till I have only about 8 divs left. Is it possible to merge the divs till I have a certain amount left?